# Safari Cache - Sensitive Data Control

Tags: ios, caching, safari

I'm having a serious issue with Safari on iPad ignoring caching requirements.

I'm working on a website which contains sensitive data that cannot, under any circumstances, allow navigation history to show what was present on the page.

I've tried telling it that it expires immediately, no-cache, and all the headers I can think of, but Safari flat out ignores it, to the point of not even showing the prompts on unload (so they don't lose their work by clicking back or navigating away.)

Answers that are a few years old seem to have no relevance, onunload is already used to provide the prompt in other browsers.  Is there something I'm missing?

To be clear: the website is currently being developed targeting the HTTP protocol but will switch to HTTPS in the future.  It's unlikely that Safari would just ignore possible sensitive information situations and think it knows best in all cases.